# ios uinavigationcontroller into uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have this problem:
my main window contains a Tab Bar Controller that manages some views of my app:
I have for example 3 buttons on the bar and 3 UIViewController, one for each button and everything works fine.

Now I wish make this: in the firstViewController, I wish add a navigation controller to manage some data... If I add the navigationcontroller into the uiviewcontroller nothing happens... how can I do for this??

thanks

Comment: I don't have some code, everything is made by the interface builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you're just doing it the wrong way round.

Currently, your structure goes:

UITabBarController -> UIViewController -> UINavigationController

It should be like this:

UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController

Comment: thanks, i think this, but in interface builder, how can I do this?

Comment: Create an empty XIB, drag a UITabBarController into the document window, open the tabBarController's details, delete the two UIViewControllers and drag a UINavigationController on the TabBarController.

Comment: thanks bjorn, but I don't understand... actually I have my mainwindow? that have a UITabBarController and works, now I need to add a navigation controller into the mainwindow.xib?